# CSS3 Webkit-transition fade in/out

Tags: css, webkit

I am having a little trouble achieving a very simply fade effect using CSS3. Here is my scenario:

I have a list a with some content in it. I also have some links, that when clicked filter the content in the list. What I would like is, when the page loads the list fades in, and every time the list is filtered, the list should disappear and than fade in with the new content.

I got the fade in on pageload working. However when I try to get the list to disappear and fade in again, I cant get that to work.

Here is a jsfiddle I created to demonstrate what I am trying to do. - http://jsfiddle.net/YeKX2/28/

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: It is considered bad etiquette to post the same question on multiple sites. I have seen this here and on Forrst and can only assume there are other locations. The reason for this is that it may be solved in one location and others then waste their time helping you in other locations.

Comment: You are correct. I posted this here as well cause initially I was not getting any answers there, and was planning to delete the forrst post. My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping it primarily webkit based and not using jQuery as you seem to be, you could do the following to achieve your goals:

```
function test(){
    document.getElementById('list').style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('list').style.opacity = '1';",2000);
}
```

You'll have to play around with the timing.

Also, to note, if you want to effect the timing of the -webkit-transition, you can use the following syntax.

```
document.getElementById('list').style['-webkit-transition'] = "opacity 2s linear";
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend including the jQuery library if at all possible. Then fading is as easy as:

jQuery("#elementId").animate({opacity:0});
jQuery("#elementId").animate({opacity:1});

Otherwise you'll end up with browser issues as opacity is handled differently in some browsers(IE) and webkit-transition is an experimental mozilla property.

Comment: I dont want to include JQuery for file size concerns. Im not worried about compatibility issues, since this is being used in a native WebOs App which supports webkit transitions.

Comment: You can combine those into one statement to make the code cleaner, also you may want to specify a timer to make it more specific. `$('#selector').animate( { opacity: 1 }, 2000).animate( { opacity: 1 }, 2000);`

Comment: 1. Sorry, I was thinking it was strange to be developing in CSS3 when it's so unsupported. I've found jQuery overcomes lots of incompatibility issues, but if you don't anticipate them... awesome. 2. Thankyou, I was aware of that. I was giving examples of fading in and fading out.